# NodeJS + ExpressJS User Login

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I am currently working on a web application that requires an user login snippet. I have built an API for getting user information and others. But I cannot let NodeJS work with sessions.

So, I have an API endpoint like this for logging in: `/api/v1/login`

The other endpoints of the API works with an `Authorization` header that contains `Token e3f0d20dae2da4e3f0d20dae2da4` value.

What I want to do is, when user not logged in, redirect them to login page and when an user gives their credentials `POST JSON` data to `/api/v1/login` and save the returning Token object from body and use it on other API calls.

Login endpoint returns this:

```
{"token" e3f0d20dae2da4e3f0d20dae2da4: , "user_id": 1104}
```

Well actually I have let people in and use that token for request but the problem that i am having is when there are two or more user, `req.session` value overrides to the latest user that logged in.

How can i let it work?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();
var https = require('https');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

var sessionMW = session(
            {
            store: FileStore(),
            secret: '$LSvj3KLSv2$$1!skv!!!!xxIf3eef5Fxc', 
            cookie: { maxAge: 36000, httpOnly: false }, 
            resave: false, 
            saveUninitialized: false
});
router.get('/api/:endpoint/:first?/:second?/:third?', sessionMW, function(req, res, next) {

    if(sess.token){
  // make http request and return json data from server
} else {
  // fail 
}

router.post("/login", sessionMW, function(req, res, next){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var options = {
      url: endpoints.login_request(),
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password
      },
      headers: {
        'User-Agent' : 'Agent',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
      }
    };
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {

        if(body.error){
            res.send('{error:1}');
        } else if(body.token) {

            req.session.token = body.token;
            req.session.user_id = body.user_id;

            res.writeHead(302, {
              'Location': '/#/home'
              //add other headers here...
            });
        }
        console.log(req.session);

        res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: Session is per user. You cannot have multiple users (from different agent/browser) ending up in the same session.

Comment: @marekful yeah i know that is the thing i am looking for. how can i make a session that contains different values for each user?

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing your actual code.  express-session does this for you if you use it correctly, but without seeing your code, we have no idea where you are going wrong.  Questions about code should contain your code!

Comment: @jfriend00 i added some code to my question.